# How to show video thumbnail with text in a ListView? 

Tags: android, listview, video

What is the best way to show video thumbnail with text in a `ListView` row?

I want to display videos from the folder on the sdcard.

Also it is needed to lock the folder for the app.

Each video will have a description and duration.

Comment: See http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom adapter class by extending the BaseAdapter class and overrride the

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method.
```

Example:

```
public class CustomListItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {    
    private Context context;

    /**
     * overrides the  getView function
     */
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.movielist_item, null,false);


        Movie ListItem = moviesList.get(position);

        /** sets the image bitmap for the imageview */
        if (moviewBmp != null)  {
            ImageView movieImg = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imgMovie);
            movieImg.setImageBitmap(movieImg );
        }

        /** sets the movie name text */
        TextView movieName = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.movieListItemName);
        movieName.setText(movieListItem.getMovieName());

        return root;
    }
}
```

and set it as a ListAdapter in your main activity.

Comment: Thanks but i need to save the thumbnail and text so that i can get the list populated with the thumbnail and text for each row when i launch the app again. Do i need to use a database (SQLite)....

Comment: You can try and save the thumbnails in sd card and in DB u can have a mapping for the filename(thumbnail) --> text. So that you can reload them whenever you want.